# How to remove entire array that have specific character

Tags: perl

I have a perl code that extract from .xls file. My .xls file is as below

```
NUMBER    NAME    ALPHABET
one       Jane        a
two       Adam        b
three     Josh        c
;four  
five      Agnes       e 
six       Mary        f
;seven 
eight     Lara        h
```

I want to extract the info and only take column 1 and 2. My perl code is as below.

```
     #!/usr/bin/perl

     use warnings;
     use strict;
     use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

     main ();

     sub main {

        my $filename = 'Book1.xls';
        my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
        my $workbook = $parser->parse( $filename );

        if ( !defined $workbook ) {
           die "-E-: cannot parse <$filename>.\n ", $parser->error(), ".\n";
        }

        my $worksheet             = $workbook -> Worksheet ( 'a' ) || die "-E-: cannot parse family pin list.\n";   
        my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet-> row_range();

        open ( my $file,"> output.txt");

        for my $row ( 1 .. $row_max ) {

           my @data;

           for my $col ( 0 ) {
              my $number = $worksheet-> get_cell( $row, $col );
              if ( $number ) {
                 push @data, $number-> value();
              }
              else {
                 push @data, '';
              }
            }

            for my $col ( 2 ) {
               my $alphabet = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
               if ( $alphabet ) {
                  push @data, $alphabet->value();
                  print $file  "@data\n";
               }
               else {
               push @data, '';
               }
            }     

     }

     close $file;

      print "done\n";
     }
```

The result is

```
    one a
    two b
    three c
    ;four 
    five e
    six f
    ;seven 
    eight h
```

I want to remove the entire array that start with string ";". I extend my code like below

```
        open ( my $file,"> output.txt");

        for my $row ( 1 .. $row_max ) {

           my @data;

           for my $col ( 0 ) {
              my $number = $worksheet-> get_cell( $row, $col );
              if ( $number ) {
                 push @data, $number-> value();
              }
              else {
                 push @data, '';
              }
            }

            for my $col ( 11 ) {
               my $alphabet = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
               if ( $alphabet ) {
                  push @data, $alphabet->value();
               }
               else {
               push @data, '';
               }
            }


      my @new_data = grep(!/;/, @data);
      my @latest_data = grep ( $_ ne '', @new_data);
      print $file  "@latest_data\n";


     }

     close $file;

      print "done\n";
     }
```

The output result produce like below.

```
     one a
     two b
     three c

     five e
     six f

     eight h
```

I don't want to be empty space. How i want to eliminate the empty space that produce result as below?

```
     one a
     two b
     three c
     five e
     six f
     eight h
```

I also try doing like this, but the result is same.

```
     for my $index (reverse 0..$#data) {
        if ( $data[$index] =~ /^;/ ) {
        splice(@data, $index, 1);
       }
     }
     print $file "@data\n";
```

Comment: Remember that *empty string* (zero length) and *blank string* (all space-type characters) are two different things. Test for `/\S+/` to find strings with content.

Comment: If you don't want empty strings in your array, why are you putting them there? 
Remove both `else { push @data, '' }` clauses and see if the data looks more useful to you.

Comment: The "_output result_" is unclear -- how do you get an empty line between six and seven? There was nothing in between these two lines in input.

Comment: `my @new_data = grep { /\S/ and !/;/ } @data;`, or an equivalent, should give what you seem to expect but again some things aren't clear in the question.

Comment: hi @truth i already remove it, but it doesn't work

Comment: hi @tadman, can you explain more

Comment: hi @zdim, i already explain in first paragraph. there is element between it

Comment: "_there is element between_"  --- no, not between six and seven, there isn't.

Comment: Hi @zdim, sorry for confusion. I already update my question

Comment: Thank you -- but now there is an empty line instead of line with "seven," while I don't see a reason to remove it and I don't see that the code removes it.  Can you check and post consistent/correct data samples?   --- Then, did you try the code from my comment above?

Comment: Sorry for trouble, the result is same as mine. There is still blank newline

Comment: Hi all, I already updated my problem. Maybe can give you guys clear understanding.

Comment: Again: did you try  `my @new_data = grep { /\S/ and !/;/ } @data;` ?

Comment: Yes, I already try it. there is still blank newline there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are looking for [next](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

@data=("one a", "two b","three c", ";four d","five e","six e","seven g","eight h")
for(@data){
    next if (/^;/);
    print $_,"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let's get your data gist

```
@data=("one a", "two b","three c", ";four d","five e","six e","seven g","eight h")
for(@data){
s/^;.*//;              # // <-- Put Replacer here between `//` , leave it to remove line
push(@new_data,$_)}
print "$_\n" for @new_data
```

Comment: Hi abdan, thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: from that code, it only remove the special character. I want to remove all the line and replace the line with element after it